# Reverting a bad git merge from GitHub

Tags: git, github, git-merge

I merged the wrong remote repo master branch into my local master branch, once I started resolving conflicts I realized my horrible mistake. However, I didn't completely resolve the conflicts and therefore didn't commit the merge.

Also, I committed my last changes to my local master copy before starting the merge.
How do I successfully revert to the last local commit before the bad merge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you still are in the merge state, you can try

```
git merge --abort
```

to check what state you are in

```
git status
```

Comment: you appear to have saved my soul

Comment: git is very forgiving when it comes to making mistakes :)